# BecomeFirstResponder() not working on UITextField

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, uitextfield, first-responder

I want to focus my `UITextfield` in my bottom toolbar, so on `ViewWillAppear` I wrote the following code:

```
textBarcode.BecomeFirstResponder ();
```

But the `textBarcode` doesn't become the focus. I also tried it with a little bit of a delay, but got the same result.

Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Tried doing it in viewDidAppear?

Comment: yes, but with the same result.
There is also a tableview in my view, maybe that causes the problem?!

Comment: Did you put the binding in from the xib/storyboard to your .h file? I forget this occasionally.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    textBarcode.delegate = self;

    [textBarcode becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check that `isUserInteraction` field is set to `true`.

```
textField.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
textField.becomeFirstResponder()
```

Comment: That property does not exist in xamarin.ios.

Answer (score 0):

You write this in `viewDidAppear`

```
[textBarcode becomeFirstResponder];
```